# How to manipulate a list with recursive function?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, recursion

I'm trying to manipulate a given list in an unusual way (at least for me).

Basically, I have the list `a` (also image 1), it has the first index as principal. Now, I want to iterate through the other indexes and if a certain value match with one of those in the first index, I want to insert the sublist of this index inside the first one.

I don't know if I was clear enough, but the goal should be the list `b` (also image 2). I think a recursive function should be used here, but I don't know how. Do you guys think it's possible?

Original list:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,5],[6,3],[10,5]]
```

Expected Output:

```
b = [[1,2,[2,5,[10,5]],3,[6,3]]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @9769953 Thanks for the suggestion! ;)

Comment: What will be the effect if the input has multiple sublists which match with the same value? What is a sublist matches with more than one value? For instance, what will `[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[2,1]]` result in?

Comment: @trincot This scenario will not happen. Inside the list "a" a certain value will appear just 2x. For example, the value 3 appears at the index 0 and then at 3. So, it will be just one match at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to record where the *first* occurrence of each number is found, recording the list in which it was found, and at which index. If then a list is found that has a value that was already encountered, the recorded list can be mutated having the matching list inserted. If there was no match (which is the case for the very first list `[1,2,3]`), then this list is just appended to the result.

Because insertion into a list will impact other insertion points, I suggest to first collect the insertion actions, and then apply them in reversed order:

Here is the code for that:

```
def solve(a):
    dct = {}
    result = []
    insertions = []
    for lst in a:
        found = None
        for i, val in enumerate(lst):
            if val in dct:
                found = val
            else:
                dct[val] = [lst, i]
        if found is None:
            result.append(lst)
        else:
            insertions.append((*dct[found], lst))

    for target, i, lst in reversed(insertions):
        target.insert(i + 1, lst)
        
    return result


# Example run:
a = [[1,2,3],[2,5],[6,3],[10,5]]
print(solve(a))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, [2, 5, [10, 5]], 3, [6, 3]]]
```

Comment: Hi @trincot, thank you for your efforts! You were so closed and I'm pretty sure it was because you were confused, and you were right in your last comment, when you said you would expected something like `[[1,[2,[2,[5,[10,5]]]],[3,[6,3]]]]`. The first value 2 doesn't need to be indented as in my original post, in your way is more readable. I'll append 2 images with the list goal and the result of your code. I'll try to work on your code and idea. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Wr6KdHFXWzr0kfKqNIw4FBhBz92CBpNC?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry for the confusion, even me I was confused with so many braces. But I updated it now and the correct output is `[[1,2,[2,5,[10,5]],3,[6,3]]]`. You have done so much and I'll continue your script, I think I can do it. Unfortunately I don't have reputation enough to give you a like, so I'll consider solved by you!